# Memory Management in iOS

Tags: ios, memory-management

Hello everyone (sorry for my english). I'm new with objetive-C and iOS programming. May you help me?

```
@interface RootViewController : UITableViewController 
{
    NSMutableArray *keysFromQuery;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray *keysFromQuery;
....
....
NSString *category = [keysFromQuery objectAtIndex:0];
```

What will happen with [keysFromQuery objectAtIndex:0] if I do: [category release];?

What will happen with category if I do after that: [keysFromQuery release];?

I don't know well how references and memory mechanisms work.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't call `-release` on `category`. You don't own the object. You must only release objects which you have taken ownership of, via NARC (new/alloc/retain/copy). For more info read the [Memory Management Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/MemoryMgmt/MemoryMgmt.html).

Answer (score 0):

If the method that returned you the object does not explicitly state that it returns a "new", "retain"ed, "alloc"ed, "created" or "copy"-ied object, you must not release it. It's that simple.

So do a release (or autorelease) only for cases like

```
[object retain];
[object copy];
[SomeClass newInstanceWithProperty: @"a"];
[[SomeClass alloc] initWithProperty: @"a"];
```

etc.

So in this case, you don't have to do anything and the "release" you mention would crash your app in all likelihood.

Comment: + after [keysFromQuery release] the object reference that you got from the container (the category string) will become invalid.

Answer (score 0):

What will happen with [keysFromQuery objectAtIndex:0] if I do: [category release];?
You shouldn't do that, because it is an autoreleased object.

What will happen with category if I do after that: [keysFromQuery release];?
The NSString is still saved, when you release keysFromQuery after the initialization.

Answer (score 0):

Dont release the objects as you don't own them  and you have not even allocated them .